# "500 status code received on GET method for API" error in Ambari - Hive Service instllation

Tags: ambari

I have ambari 2.1.2 installed on CentOS 6.4. I have the following two questions related to Hive service installation through ambari.

Question 1:

On the Ambari Dashboard, what is “MySQL Server / Hive”?. When Ambari was installed, wasn’t MySQL server already installed initally?. Will installing the “MySQL server/ Hive” service, overwrite the existing MySQL server?.

Question 2:

When I try to install “MySQL server / Hive” service, I get the following “Get Method for API” error (please see details at the end of this post). I tried to create hive database manually also and selected “Existing MySQL database” option from the config section, but this error never goes away. I am unable to find any logs and therefore stuck.

Following is the first error message that is displayed in a dialog box.

> 500 status code received on GET method for API:
>   /api/v1/clusters/SGICluster/hosts?fields=Hosts/rack_info,Hosts/host_name,Hosts/maintenance_state,Hosts/public_host_name,Hosts/cpu_count,Hosts/ph_cpu_count,alerts_summary,Hosts/host_status,Hosts/last_heartbeat_time,Hosts/ip,host_components/HostRoles/state,host_components/HostRoles/maintenance_state,host_components/HostRoles/stale_configs,host_components/HostRoles/service_name,host_components/HostRoles/desired_admin_state,metrics/disk,metrics/load/load_one,Hosts/total_mem,Hosts/os_arch,Hosts/os_type,metrics/cpu/cpu_system,metrics/cpu/cpu_user,metrics/memory/mem_total,metrics/memory/mem_free,stack_versions/HostStackVersions,stack_versions/repository_versions/RepositoryVersions/repository_version,stack_versions/repository_versions/RepositoryVersions/id,stack_versions/repository_versions/RepositoryVersions/display_name&minimal_response=true&sortBy=Hosts/host_name.asc

Error message: Server Error

If I close the dialog box, by pressing "ok" green button, then the error message is shorted as shown below

> 500 status code received on GET method for API:
>   /api/v1/clusters/SGICluster/requests?to=end&page_size=10&fields=Request
>
> Error message: Server Error

Answer (score 1):

I found that trying to install MySQL will fail because there is already an instance of MySQL server. The solution is to ignore the installation of MySQL server and use the existing mysql server instance, which can be mentioned from the advance configuration section in Ambari.